# Why does linking against both sdl2 and udev cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, linux, linker, sdl-2, udev

I have the following really dumb C program:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main () {
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
}
```

If I compile it and link against `sdl2`, all is well:

```
[nix-shell:~/work/on-the-limit]$ gcc oddity.c -lSDL2 -o oddity

[nix-shell:~/work/on-the-limit]$ ./oddity
```

However, if I also link against `udev`...

```
[nix-shell:~/work/on-the-limit]$ gcc oddity.c -lSDL2 -ludev -o oddity

[nix-shell:~/work/on-the-limit]$ ./oddity 
Segmentation fault
```

... a segmentation fault happens.

`gdb` has the following to say:

```
[nix-shell:~/work/on-the-limit]$ gdb ./oddity 
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.10
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./oddity...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/ollie/work/on-the-limit/oddity 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/nix/store/npfsi1d9ka8zwnxzn3sr08hbwvpapyk7-glibc-2.21/lib/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff736b36a in strlen () from /nix/store/483br9kb3f5igsgmb6aqsjhl2ipj2bxr-glibc-2.21/lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff736b36a in strlen () from /nix/store/483br9kb3f5igsgmb6aqsjhl2ipj2bxr-glibc-2.21/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7fbb54b in strpcpy () from /nix/store/m3k7v0cy7zh6qbjqhrxgd36p105qqf0q-systemd-217/lib/libudev.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff7fbb6b3 in strscpy () from /nix/store/m3k7v0cy7zh6qbjqhrxgd36p105qqf0q-systemd-217/lib/libudev.so.1
#3  0x00007ffff7fb8f3d in device_new_from_parent.isra.7.lto_priv () from /nix/store/m3k7v0cy7zh6qbjqhrxgd36p105qqf0q-systemd-217/lib/libudev.so.1
#4  0x00007ffff7fb6140 in udev_device_get_parent () from /nix/store/m3k7v0cy7zh6qbjqhrxgd36p105qqf0q-systemd-217/lib/libudev.so.1
#5  0x00007ffff4c9b85a in loader_get_pci_id_for_fd () from /run/opengl-driver/lib/libGL.so.1
#6  0x00007ffff4c9be68 in loader_get_driver_for_fd () from /run/opengl-driver/lib/libGL.so.1
#7  0x00007ffff4c95126 in dri2CreateScreen () from /run/opengl-driver/lib/libGL.so.1
#8  0x00007ffff4c748d4 in __glXInitialize () from /run/opengl-driver/lib/libGL.so.1
#9  0x00007ffff4c70c1b in GetGLXPrivScreenConfig.part.2 () from /run/opengl-driver/lib/libGL.so.1
#10 0x00007ffff4c70d4d in glXChooseVisual () from /run/opengl-driver/lib/libGL.so.1
#11 0x00007ffff7b92288 in X11_GL_LoadLibrary () from /nix/store/qcf0jg20x3fnb09p4xc1y5dsbz84m7h9-SDL2-2.0.3/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#12 0x00007ffff7b89567 in SDL_CreateWindow_REAL () from /nix/store/qcf0jg20x3fnb09p4xc1y5dsbz84m7h9-SDL2-2.0.3/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff7b89180 in SDL_VideoInit_REAL () from /nix/store/qcf0jg20x3fnb09p4xc1y5dsbz84m7h9-SDL2-2.0.3/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff7ac8317 in SDL_Init_REAL () from /nix/store/qcf0jg20x3fnb09p4xc1y5dsbz84m7h9-SDL2-2.0.3/lib/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#15 0x00000000004008b6 in main () at oddity.c:4
```

Comment: If your program does not depend on anything in `libusb`, as your first example demonstrates, then why are you linking against that library?

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is a minimal example, my actual project does need both libraries.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Just FYI, -ludev is enough - seems that it's not -lusb that is to blame (but it does bring in udev on the way).

Comment: Very strange, this looks like a very environment-specific problem. Based on the traceback you're using mesa - the 'loader_get_pci_id_for_fd' function is the one that looks up which driver to pull in for your hardware. An interesting thing is that mesa actually uses dlopen() to load libudev.so; you need to check library paths to make sure it loaded the same one as you linked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a program's behavior differs depending only on how it is linked, then that must result from different function implementations being [dynamically] linked in one case and the other.  Beyond that, to answer in any detail would require examining details of *all* the libraries involved.

Nevertheless, at this point I am inclined to observe that you apparently are relying heavily on RPATHs, which is highly questionable.  It is especially questionable that you appear to be resolving the C standard library via RPATH (as is evident from the first line of your back trace) instead of using the system's version.

It would be best to influence dynamic linking by configuring the dynamic linker, instead of by embedding RPATHs in your program or libraries.  If the objective is to use different libraries than the system's defaults, then you might find it useful to establish an alternative chroot environment in which your program could run.  Under all circumstances, be certain that the compiler, static linker, dynamic linker, all libraries on which your program relies, and the program itself all agree about which version of each library is to be used.

Comment: The -rpath stuff is just what I'm getting from `pkg-config --libs`, but that's fairly standard for how things are packaged in NixOS. I'll look deeper into it though.

Comment: I've simplified the GCC calls and the same still happens, so it at least doesn't seem to be how I calling `gcc`.

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction, and as @kepstin mentions - mesa uses dlopen to open udev. The real problem here is the environment I was building in was linking against a *different* udev from the systems currently running udev. If I link against exactly the same version as what is running, then all is well. I'll have to find a way to get my build environment set up correctly, but thank god we've finally found the problem!